# Rails validation In attribute table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new to ROR.
i am building a classified ads app, i have the following tables in my database:
(some fields have been removed for simplicity)

### **Table Uers**

This table stores all the users.

**user_id**
name
email
password

### **Table Ads**

This table stores all the ads.

**ad_id**
users_user_id (FK)
title
desc
cat_id (FK)
created_at

*Sample data:*

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  ad_id  |  users_user_id  |  title    |  desc        |  cat_id  | created_at |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |       1         |  iphone 4 |  brand new   |    2     | 30-11-2015 |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### **Table categories**

This table stores all the available categories. cat_id in the ads table relates to cat_id in this table.

**cat_id**
category
parent_cid

*Sample data:*

```
-------------------------------------------
|cat_id| category            | parent_cid |
-------------------------------------------
|1     | Electronics         | NULL       |
|2     | Mobile Phone        | 1          |
|3     | Apartments          | NULL       |
|4     | Apartments - Sale   | 3          |
-------------------------------------------
```

### Table ads_attribute

This table contains all the available attributes for a particular category. Relates to categories table.

**attr_id**
cat_id (FK)
attr_label
attr_name

*Sample data:*

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|attr_id | cat_id | attr_label       | attr_name          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|1       | 2      | Operating System | Operating_System   |
|2       | 2      | Is Touch Screen  | Touch_Screen       |
|3       | 2      | Manufacturer     | Manufacturer       |
|4       | 3      | Bedrooms         | Bedrooms           |
|5       | 3      | Total Area       | Area               |
|6       | 3      | Posted By        | Posted_By          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

### Table ads_attr_value

This table stores the attribute value for each ad in ads table.

**attr_val_id**
attr_id (FK)
ad_id
attr_val

*Sample data:*

```
---------------------------------------------
|attr_val_id | attr_id | ad_id | attr_val   |
---------------------------------------------
|1           | 1       | 1     | Ios 8      |
|2           | 2       | 1     | 1          |
|3           | 3       | 1     | Apple      |
---------------------------------------------
```

What is the best way (the rails way) to validate the data before storing it in the the ads_attr_value table, given the fact that the values would be in select fields and the user can change them easily for example from Ios 8 to "blabla".
I've thought of storing all the possible values for each attribute in a new table and then check if a value sent by the user exist in that table before storing it in the ads_attr_value. what do you think? I am sure that there is a better way.
thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The rails way would probably to define your relationships with ActiveRecord associations : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

Therefore you could easily define on your model

```
class AdsAttrVal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :ad
    validates :ad, presence: true
end
```

However please keep in mind that rails way to store an id of the table is to name it "id" and not "*model*_id" like you did ("user_id", "id"). My exemple suppose that the rails way is respected...

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question, for instance how can i verify that the operating system belongs to "Ios 8" or "Ios 9" or "android" before storing it in the database, and that's just for the Electronic category attributes, what about Cars category it also has attributes how to verify that the user didn't mess up with the form and changed the values in a select tag

Comment: i know about rails associations, and i know that the rails uses id as convention in lieu of user_id, but i can't see how to verify the data before storing it, or at least i can't see how to do it with this database scheme

Comment: Indeed, I have misunderstood the question. However, I am not sure to understand how your form works. You can easily use select tag to display "ios 8" while sending to your controller the corresponding ads_attr_value_id. Therefore, you can seed your base with the allowed operating system and pass to your program only id => therefore no risk of "blabla"

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the validations you want inside `<yourModel>.rb` (the model file) . For exame if you want to validate if `ad_id` is a number you should add the numericality parameter in the `validates` statement, see below:

```
class AdsAttrValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :ad_id, numericality: true

  #validate if add_att_value has the permitted values
  validate :myCustomValidation

  def myCustomValidation
    #your logic of validation goes here
    #you can access here all the fields from this object recently created
    if attr_val == something
       #do something
    end
  end

end
```

See that validations from rails have an `s` at the end (`validates`), and your own written validations do not have (`validate`).
This validations are executed when creating the object before storing in database in order to see if it complies the validations and not stored it it does not comply. You can add errors in your own validation to let the user know what gone wrong. Go further with [this reading of validations in ruby on rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)